# Change submit button with learnr package

Tags: r, shiny, learnr

I am using the learnr package and I would like to know if there is an easy way to change the caption of the submit button? Instead of "Submit Answer", I would like to change it to "Validate", for example. I could not find information in the package help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hardcoded, maybe make your own version of the function. Change [this line quiz.R#L113](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/blob/master/R/quiz.R#L113):

```
x$checkAnswerText <- "Submit Answer"
```

To:

```
x$checkAnswerText <- "Validate"
```

And see the related [GitHub issue 108](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues/108).